# Expression cannot be assigned: when trying to use multiple if statements in a for loop

Tags: apex, batch, if

There is an object tm__c which contains LinkedIn URl(URL field),two picklist fields: Backgroundcheck(Yes, NO) and Verification(Pending, Not started, Done)
I want to create a batch class so that I have to update a value for Verfication field based on URL and backgroundcheckfields with below scenarios for all the records:
If Linkedin__c is blank then verification = Not started
If linkedin__c is not blank and baclgroundcheck__c='No' then verification__c='Pending'
If linkedin__c is not blank and baclgroundcheck__c='Yes' then verification__c='Done'

I have created the below class which is not completed but I am getting "Expression cannot be assigned error for second if statement.

```
global class 43Batchclass implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
    global static Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc){
        return Database.getQueryLocator(
             'SELECT Id, Background_Check_Done__c, LinkedIn_Profile__c, Verification_status__c FROM Trainer_Master__c');
    }

    global  static void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Trainer_Master__c> t){
        List<Trainer_Master__c> a = new List<Trainer_Master__c>();
        for(Trainer_Master__c b: t){
            if( string.isblank(b.LinkedIn_Profile__c)){
                b.Verification_status__c = 'Details Needed';
            }
            if(  string.contains(b.Background_Check_Done__c = 'No')) {
                b.Verification_status__c = 'Non Verified';
            }
        }
        
    }
 
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){ }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is here: `if(  string.contains(b.Background_Check_Done__c = 'No'))`.

1. `b.Background_Check_Done__c = 'No'` is an assignment. A check would be `b.Background_Check_Done__c == 'No'`.
2. `contains()` isn't a static method of `String` class, so you must call it on an instance.
3. Its signature is `public Boolean contains(String substring)` so even if you write `contains(b.Background_Check_Done__c == 'No')` it will be wrong since `b.Background_Check_Done__c == 'No'` evaluate to a Boolean.

Since it's a picklist field, you don't need `contains()`, you can just write `if ('No' == b.Background_Check_Done__c)`. Keep in mind that if you put constants as left operators, you'll never get such error: if mistype and forgot an `=`, you'll get a compile time error.

That said, actually the code doesn't match your requirements (even the update is missing):

> If Linkedin__c is blank then verification = Not started
> If linkedin__c is not blank and baclgroundcheck__c='No' then verification__c='Pending'
> If linkedin__c is not blank and baclgroundcheck__c='Yes' then verification__c='Done'

It should be:

```
global  static void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Trainer_Master__c> t){
    for(Trainer_Master__c b: t){
        if(String.isblank(b.LinkedIn_Profile__c)){
            b.Verification_status__c = 'Not started';
        } else {
            b.Verification_status__c = ('No' == b.Background_Check_Done__c) ? 'Pending' : 'Done';
        }
    }
    update t;
}
```

By the way, you could add a WHERE condition to your query in order to retrieve only the records that need an update:
`WHERE (LinkedIn_Profile__c = NULL AND Verification_status__c != 'Not started') OR (LinkedIn_Profile__c != NULL AND ((Background_Check_Done__c = 'No' AND Verification_status__c != 'Pending') OR (Background_Check_Done__c = 'Yes' AND Verification_status__c != 'Done')))`

Comment: The parentheses are unnecessary in the ternary operator. Also, while it's nice to see a reference to a Yoda condition after all these years, I wouldn't generally advise it as a normal coding practice. It's unusual enough in Apex (and most languages) that it'd increase cognitive load unnecessarily (some developers may even read it as "incorrect" code, even though it's just fine).

Comment: @sfdcfox A good IDE should raise a warning in cases like `if (variable = foo)`, making Yoda condition almost useless, but there are some cases, in Java, that it let you avoid some nulls checks, i.e. instead of `(s != null) && s.equals("hello");` you could write `"hello".equals(s)` (it will never throw a NPE). Anyway I think that in simple cases like comparing two strings the change of cognitive load is negligible, but I must admit that I never wrote `null != var`. About the parentheses, yes they are unnecessary, like the brackets of the for-loop or the if-else, it's just a personal preference.